# Count total number of words of all documents pointing to specific fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Someone asked this question but no one seems to answer or tried to suggest possible ways to solve it: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/count-the-number-of-words-in-the-field-elastic-search-6-2/121373

Now, I'm trying to produce a report from Elasticsearch to count the number of **WORDS / TOKENS** from a specific field called **title** and **content**

Is there a proper `aggregation` for this?

For example, I have this query:

```
GET web/_search
{
  "query":{
     "bool":{
        "must":[
           {
              "query_string":{
                 "fields":[
                    "title",
                    "content"
                 ],
                 "query":"((\"Hello\") AND (\"World\")"
              }
           },
           {
              "range":{
                 "pub_date":{
                    "from":1569456000,
                    "to":1570060800
                 }
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

And for example, this query produced **23 DOCUMENTS**, I want to make a response telling me how **MANY** words do those 23 documents contain based from the **title** and **content** fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage the [`token_count` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html). In your index, you can add a sub-field of type `token_count` to your `title` and `content` fields, like this:

```
PUT web
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "length": {
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "length": {
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then, in order to find out the number of tokens, you can simply run a `sum` aggregation on the `.length` sub-field, like this:

```
POST web/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "title_tokens": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "title.length"
      }
    },
    "content_tokens": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "content.length"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using data type called [token_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html) It will calculate and store the count of tokens for each text. This count value can be utilized to get the token count of fields

```
PUT index18
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "token_count",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "token_count",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index18",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "edJPtW0BVHM68p7X-Wlu",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Mayor Isko"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index18",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "etJQtW0BVHM68p7XGmmr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Isko"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query

```
GET index18/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "aggs": {
    "WordCount": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "title.length"
      }
    }
  }
}
```